# Rotating one quaternion via the rotation of another

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation, quaternions

**Context**

I'm working with Mixed Reality and Unity, and attempting to control the 3d rotation of a GameObject with my hands.

Here's what I have so far:

```
    Vector3 _lefthand = new Vector3(Left.x, Left.y, Left.z);
    Vector3 _righthand = new Vector3(Right.x, Right.y, Right.z);
    _myObject.transform.rotation = Quaternion.FromToRotation(Vector3.right, _righthand - _lefthand));
```

That block is contained within an `IEnumerator` coroutine, which starts when an `if` statement in `Update` is met. The `if` checks for a specific hand pose, so the rotation 'starts' when the hand poses are active, and 'stops' when they're not.

What I have works well for one small rotation, but falls down if I want to rotate the object several times, because the rotation of `_myObject` just matches the current quaternion created by the present `Vector3` positions of my hands.

**Question**

How could I rotatate `_myObject` from it's *current rotation* to a new rotation, by a margin of the difference between my hands start and finish positions?

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion-operator_multiply.html

Comment: @derHugo I think this is more of an XY question - the most straightforward solution is to apply per-frame deltas instead of a delta from the very start of the rotation procedure. Also it's not immediately apparent from the documentation that to rotate `rhs` by `lhs` in the world frame of reference is also `lhs * rhs` - the docs only speak explicitly about rotating `lhs` by `rhs` in the local frame of reference of `lhs`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the start of each frame, cache the rotation and the left hand -> right hand direction then use `Quat B * Quat A` to rotate A by B in world space, or by using `transform.Rotate` with `Space.World`.

```
IEnumerator DoRotate()
{        
    Vector3 previousLeftHand = new Vector3(Left.x, Left.y, Left.z);
    Vector3 previousRightHand = new Vector3(Right.x, Right.y, Right.z);  

    Vector3 previousFromLeftToRight = previousRightHand - previousLeftHand;

    while (!doneFlag)
    {
        yield return null;

        Vector3 newLeftHand = new Vector3(Left.x, Left.y, Left.z);
        Vector3 newRightHand = new Vector3(Right.x, Right.y, Right.z);

        Vector3 newFromLeftToRight = newRightHand - newLeftHand;

        Quaternion deltaRotationWorld = Quaternion.FromToRotation(
                previousFromLeftToRight, newFromLeftToRight);

        _myObject.transform.rotation = deltaRotationWorld * _myObject.transform.rotation;
        // or _myObject.transform.Rotate(deltaRotationWorld, Space.World);

        previousFromLeftToRight = newFromLeftToRight;

    }
}
```

You could use this technique except only caching a start rotation & the start hand positions, but it would often result in unexpected rotation along the local axis going between the hands. Using per-frame deltas minimizes that.

Comment: Thanks @Ruzihm this worked nicely and was pretty easy to understand.